# Blogger Drop down menu not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

My blog's menu http://www.airinaapril.blogspot.com was working fine way back. But then I noticed that it is not hovering on the drop down list. I am not very knowledgeable with codes. Can somebody help me?

Here is the code:

```
<div id='mbwnavbar'>
  <ul id='mbwnav'>
    <li>
      <a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/'>HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/p/about.html'>ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/review'>REVIEWS</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/food'>FOOD</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/others'>OTHERS</a></li>
        </ul>
   </li>
    <li>
      <a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/events'>EVENTS</a>
    </li>
     <li>
      <a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/Book%20talk'>BOOK TALK</a>
    </li>
     <li>
      <a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/travel'>TRAVEL</a>
    </li>
     <li>
       <a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/Nursing'>NURSING</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/Nurse%27s%20call'>NURSE'S CALL</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/IELTS'>IELTS</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/To%20Canada'>TO CANADA, I WILL GO</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/personal'>PERSONAL</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/people%20of%20my%20year'>PEOPLE OF MY YEAR</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/It%27s%20all%20relative'>IT'S ALL RELATIVE</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/Choir'>CHOIR</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://airinaapril.blogspot.com/search/label/Me'>ME</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='http://airinadesuyo.journoportfolio.com'>PRESS</a>
        </li></ul>


</div>
```

Comment: You need to show either CSS code for this HTML page

Comment: Also I dont see anything wrong with your drop-down-menus with my browser(Firefox). If your using internet explorer tell us what version you use.

Comment: Are you sure? I checked it using Firefox 41.0.2 and it is very slow or sometimes not hovering at all. Where can I find the CSS code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue occures when google fonts are getting loaded. If you take out this part of the code, the hover over effect works ok.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      WebFontConfig = {
        google: {
          families: ['Bentham', 'Josefin Sans'],
          api: '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?kit=74CQnMKN2BkXEmUj8YT1AfI9iBPEt1ZCKPy57IUpIMg'
        },
        loading: function() {
          if (window.jstiming) window.jstiming.load.tick('webfontLoading');
        },
        active: function() {
          if (window.jstiming) window.jstiming.load.tick('webfontActive');
        }
      };
      (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })();

    </script>
```

the issue is though that
-navigation styles are off
-you don't have a right font.

So: rather then using JS to load your fonts use this, newer way of embedding fonts:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bentham' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And then you need to fix the styling of the menu to make sure that it has the right height.

Comment: Hi! I tried removing the codes you mentioned but it is still not working properly. What is JS? and how can I find it? thanks

Comment: JS is javascript. Try to remove the code above, and clear your cookies / cache.